# Programmatic change of NLog variable value is not taking effect

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

This is my NLog.config in which I've defined a variable `logLevelMaxLength`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <variable name="logLevelMaxLength" value="20" />

  <targets>

        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logfile.log" layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=${logLevelMaxLength}:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${logger}|${message}" />
        <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logconsole" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I am using that variable value to pad the level printing in the log. But then in my code, I'm updating that value and trying to get the logging to use the new value for padding:

```
MessageBox.Show(LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logLevelMaxLength"].ToString()); //Shows old value: 20

LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logLevelMaxLength"] = "10";

MessageBox.Show(LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logLevelMaxLength"].ToString()); //Shows new value: 10
```

I am able to change the value programmatically and confirm the change via a MessageBox, but still the logs printed are still using the old value for printing. I even tried using the `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();` command, but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: NLog Config Variables are special. When declared and used inside `NLog.config` then they work like text-tranformation with search/replace. But when modifying NLog Config Variables at runtime then the same search/replace magic doesn't occur (Unless the property is a NLog Layout). Guess you are waiting for this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3382

Comment: Current work-around is to declare the entire Layout as NLog Config Variable, and then update the NLog Config Variable with the new complete updated Layout. Using `${var:mySpecialLayout}`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 1):

When using `${logLevelMaxLength}` the value can't be changed runtime. If you need this, use this syntax:  `${var:logLevelMaxLength}`

See [docs of the `var` layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer)

> Performance is better when using NLog variables directly in config file (Ex. `${myvar}`), instead of using this layout renderer that always performs dynamic lookup (Ex. `${var:myvar}`). But this layout renderer reacts to NLog variables being modified at runtime.

#### Padding property

Unfortunately the padding property of ${pad} isn't layoutable (it's not of type Layout), so you can't use a dynamic value.

There are multiple solutions for that:

1. Edit the value from the API (e.g. C#)
2. Write your own padding layout renderer, which works with Layouts: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer
3. Current work-around is to declare the entire Layout as NLog Config Variable, and then update the NLog Config Variable with the new complete updated Layout. Using ${var:mySpecialLayout}. See also (Thanks Rolf Kristensen!)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried that too .. But then the program refuses to run because of this exception: `System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'NetworkAssistantNamespace.Program' threw an exception.'`

Comment: inner exceptions from nlog internal log: `NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'Layout' on File Target[logfile] ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'Padding' on Layout Renderer: ${pad} ---> System.Exception: ${var is not a valid value for Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: @Ahmad updated my answer, but also see snakefoot comments